# Extract series of XML elements' values into an array

Tags: java, xml, dom

This code needs to extract data from in XML file.
Specifically it needs to iterate over it, looking for a node called `CHARGE_CODES` that repeats over and over and has several elements.
it needs to extract the values of one of them, called `CODE`.
the XML contents are composed of repeating blocks like these:

```
<CHARGE_CODE>
  <CODE>some value</CODE>
  <OtherElement>some value</Otherelement>
  ..
  ..
</CHARGE_CODE>
..
..
```

The code then needs to put these values of "CODE" into an array.
I create several arrays like these each containing the values of one of these tags.

Then all these arrays are used to send SOAP POSTS and enter together (all elements from one CHARGE_CODES block) into a database as the details of a service.

This code contains one such array collecting the values of one node.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        String test = "URL";
        File inputFile = new File(test);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList blocks = doc.getElementsByTagName("CHARGE_CODE");
        ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<blocks.getLength(); i++){
            Element  children = (Element) blocks.item(i);
            if(children.getElementsByTagName("CODE") != null){
                codes.add(children.getElementsByTagName("CODE").item(0).getTextContent());
            }else{
                codes.add("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks a lot like something that XPath is well suited to.  You might find that the subset of XPath support in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) is good enough for this task.

Comment: You mean I should use python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Review, you can use xpath with java too. If you want to send a message to an user use @name in your message, see [how-do-comment-replies-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for further informations

Comment: Oops, sorry - I had just reviewed a Python question, so had those docs to hand.  I don't know what XPath libraries exist for Java, but it may be worth researching, as you may find that much of the work is done for you.

Comment: Are you sure your code works ? Your main method throws no exceptions and there and you used  `"CHARGE_CODE"` instead of `"CHARGE_CODES"`.

Comment: @dariosicily yes, the CHARGE_CODES is a mistake, ill correct it.

Comment: XPath for java is in the package javax.xml.xpath. All contained in the standard library.